# How to know which sub module are in use with python module?? unable to create requirement.txt for docker image

Tags: python, pip

I am in the process of deploying my flask solution over docker. To deploy my flask solution over docker I need to prepare requirement.txt file.

Due to not having information about which version of python module I am using , I am unable to prepare requirement.txt file.

As I am using python and flask, so I have version information about flask and python but how to know which submodules required by flask and what's their version ??

Comment: `pip freeze list`

Comment: but it will list all modules installed in my python environment. right ??   What is the feasible way to get only those modules and dependent modules which are in use in my project?? like flask required numpy etc

Comment: Yes, it will print out all of external libraries with its version that you had installed on your virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

This will create an requirements.txt file with all your installed packages on that python environment

But you don't need to worry about flask dependencies, they are automatically installed

Comment: thanks tried it. but it is listing all modules. is it possible to list out only modules used in individual solution rather than all modules??

Comment: I don't know a way to list the packages from just one project. I usually create virtual environments for each project.

I advice you to read about virtual environments. https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/